# Linkage error in websphere 8.5 for SAXParser

Tags: websphere, linkageerror

I am facing an issue related to linkage when i deployed my application websphere 8.5

```
Error in the XML parsing of the included Input Stream: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when resolving method "javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.parse(Lorg/xml/sax/InputSource;Lorg/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler;)V" : loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@aa54261e" of class "com/XMLParser/CreateParser" and loader "com/ibm/oti/vm/BootstrapClassLoader@1c4565b7" of class "javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser" have different types for the method signature.
```

I have the following jars in my class path.
I have set the loader to PARENT_LAST.

I tried to debug the class alone using a main method and found that it is taking the impl of saxparser of jdk 1.5 rt.jar and it is working as expected.  After deploying the ear it is throwing the exception while the code hits the SAXParser.parse(InputSoruce,DefaultHandler) method.

jaxb-impl 2.2.6,
jaxb-libs-1.0.5,
jaxb-xjc-2.0EA3,
dom4j-1.1,
sax 2.0.1

Does any one have any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class loader has visibility to two copies of org.xml.sax.  The first because you've included the SAX APIs in your PARENT_LAST class loader, and the second indirectly via javax.xml.parsers in the JRE.  You either need to remove the SAX API JAR from your application or you need to add the javax.xml (and perhaps more) APIs + impl to your application.